javascript swap two elements in an array issue using arrays destructuring
I'm a novice in Javascript and I was stuck in a leetcode question due to the js syntax, which involves swapping two elements in an array. The complete code in JS is shown below:


/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var permute = function(nums) {
    const n = nums.length
    const rs = []
    const dfs_swap = (idx, path) => {
        if (idx >= n - 1) {
            rs.push([...path])
            return
        }

        for (let i = idx; i < n; i++) {
            [path[i], path[idx]] = [path[idx], path[i]]
            dfs_swap(idx + 1, path)
            [path[i], path[idx]] = [path[idx], path[i]]
        }

    }
    dfs_swap(0, [...nums])
    return rs
};
// test case below
permute([1,2,3])



But I received the an runtime error below:
Line 17 in solution.js
            [path[i], path[idx]] = [path[idx], path[i]]
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '2')
    Line 17: Char 34 in solution.js (dfs_swap)
    Line 16: Char 13 in solution.js (dfs_swap)
    Line 21: Char 5 in solution.js (permute)
    Line 35: Char 19 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 24: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
Node.js v20.10.0

I was using the debugger to look into the code at runtime and found everything looked fine there before getting that runtime error. I even tried to run this in my Chrome's developer console but ended up with the same error.
Then, I only added one thing to solve this error: I added a semicolon after dfs_swap(idx + 1, path), that is:
        for (let i = idx; i < n; i++) {
            [path[i], path[idx]] = [path[idx], path[i]]
            dfs_swap(idx + 1, path);
            [path[i], path[idx]] = [path[idx], path[i]]
        }

After this, I was even more confused about this and ChatGPT failed to give me a plausible answer for that. I pretty much appreciate any help or insights on this, and thank you in advance!

Do you know the rules for automatic semicolon insertions (ASI)? If not, always use a semicolon.

Also, does the person who will maintain the code after you know the rules for ASI? Use semicolons in case they can find out where you live.
